# Python: Counting the occurrence from 2 big arrays

Tags: python

I have the following script that counts the occurrence of values from one array to another

```
array_1 = [1,2,0,5,7,0]
array_2 = [1,0,1,1,9,6]
# on array 2 there are 3 occurrence of 1, and 1 occurrence of zero, but because there is another zero at array_1 add 1 more. 3+2 = 5

for r in array_1:
     total_count = total_count + array_2.count(r)

print("total sum: {0}".format(total_count))
```

its ok when dealing with small array size, but struggles when the array size increases (1 million for `array_1` and 1 million `array_2`). Is there a better to approach this?

sorry for the confusion, i updated the question a little bit.

Comment: why has array2 not also 1 occurence of 9? because 9 not in array1?

Comment: i need to count the reoccurring numbers in array 2 using array 1.

Comment: Don't accept my solution, use the one from Netwave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: [The answer by @Netwave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50533752/8472976) is five time faster.

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It is be faster, because it only iterates ones of the list.

```
from collections import Counter

array_1 = [1,2,0,5,7]
array_2 = [1,0,1,1,9]

c = Counter(array_1)
total_count = sum(c[x] for x in array_2)

print("total sum: {0}".format(total_count))
```

Comment: I would add that calling `count` in a loop requires a separate pass over the list for every `count` call and this is why `collections.Counter` is faster.

Comment: @Megalng yes his answer is faster, but i have a large number of arrays and the result of yours is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `set` instead of a list:

```
array1_set = set(array_1)
total_count = sum(1 for x in array_2 if x in array1_set)
```

Comment: i need to recount even the duplicates

Comment: it does, but the result is different from what i need.

Comment: @Led, you mean duplicates in `array_1`?

Comment: @Led I don't think you understand the meaning of the word "correctly". How is the result different from what you need?

Comment: yes duplicates must be recounted both array 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of repeated numbers in array 1, you'll save time by caching  them (building a dict in the form {number: count}). A typical caching function would look like this:

```
counts = {}
def get_count(number):
    if number in counts:
        return counts[number]
    else:
        count = your_counting_function(number)
        counts[number] = count
        return count
```

This behavior is packaged into the [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator, so that function can be simplified as:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_count(number):
    return array_2.count(number)
```

This would be a pretty efficient approach if you have a small number of distinct values in array 1—say, a random shuffle of the integers 1 through 10. This is sometimes referred to as array_1 having a *low cardinality* (a cardinality of 10).

If you have a high cardinality (say 900k distinct values in an array of 1M values), a better optimization would be precomputing *all* the counts before you even start, so that you only have to make one pass over array_2. Dict lookups are much, much faster than counting through the whole array.

```
array_2_counts = {}
for number in array_2:
    if number in counts:
        array_2_counts[number] += 1
    else:
        array_2_counts[number] = 1


total_count = 0
for number in array_1:
    total_count += array_2_counts[number]
```

Python has a built-in for this, too! The above code can be simplified using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

array_2_counter = new Counter(array_2)
for number in array_1:
    total_count += array_2_counter[number]
```

Comment: thank you for the elaboration, but i will choose Megalng's answer because he/she posted first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_1 = [1,2,0,5,7]
array_2 = [1,0,1,1,9]
array_2_counts = {}
for number in array_1:
 freq=array_2.count(number)
 array_2_counts.update({number:freq})
print(array_2_counts)
```